# JavaScript constraints on object's values

Tags: javascript, books

I'm currectly reading the book `JavaScript: The Good Parts` by *Douglas Crockford*.

The opening of the Chapter 3 `Objects` immediately confuses me with a (possible) contradiction. I re-read the two paragraphs at least a dozen of times and am still not sure which part is correct, and which is wrong.

I will definitely try things out in the browser console, but I don't want to miss an important detail in case there's no error nor contradiction in the book. Could anyone clarify me this?

> An object is a container of properties, where a property has a name and a value.
>   ...
>   **A property value can be any JavaScript value except for `undefined`**.
>
> ...
>   **There is no constraint** on the names of new properties or **on the values of properties**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have my copy of the book on hand, but `undefined` is valid for both property names and values. It's simple enough to demo in a browser console.

```
var obj = {
    foo: undefined
};
obj.bar = undefined;
obj[undefined] = undefined;

obj.hasOwnProperty("foo");  // === true
obj.propertyIsEnumerable("bar");  // === true
obj.propertyIsEnumerable(undefined);  // === true
```

The O'Reilly website maintains lists of [confirmed](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596517748) and [unconfirmed](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596517748) errata. If you feel the book is in error, you can submit your own errata.

Answer (score 1):

What he is really saying, without coming right out and saying it, is **JavaScript objects are just key-value pairs.**

In Java, it would be a `HashTable<String, Object>`

In C# it would be a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

JavaScript objects are just a bag of keys as strings, and values associated with each key being any type that exists in JavaScript.

```
var x = {
    foo: false
};
```

You can access the `foo` property value be either means:

```
x.foo
x["foo"]
```

Furthermore, you can use any valid string characters for a property name if you use the array notation:

```
x["@%$!$5@^^"] = 8;
```

This array notation mimics the syntax of accessing or setting values on a Dictionary object in C#:

```
Dictionary<string, object> x = new Dictionary<string, object>();

x["foo"] = false;
x["@%$!$5@^^"] = 8;
```

Hence the association that Douglas Crockford is making about JavaScript objects being "a container of properties, where a property has a name and a value".

The last thing he might not have written (or you haven't read it yet) is property names in JavaScript are always converted to strings:

```
x[undefined] = 4;
x["undefined"] = 9;
```

Screenshot from Firefox's debugging tools:

[image: Screenshot of Firefox debugging tools illustrating undefined property]

Comment: While all you're saying is understandable and correct, the focus of my question is on highlighted parts of the text. One sentence is saying the values cannot be `undefined` (which is a constraint), while the other sentence says there are no constraints on values. _This_ is what's confusing.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko: He is just not correct, in this case. Maybe a typo that didn't get caught during the editing process? Could also stem for `x.foo === undefined` is a common test to see if a property has been defined and `x.foo = undefined` kind of invalidates that test?